# Create a single elastic search cluster that can support multiple tenants

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to create create a single elastic search cluster which can be shareable using multiple tenants

I tried searching but could not get any reference related to this

Comment: I don't understand your question. what would you like to achieve?  please elaborate

Comment: Elasticsearch is being used as one of infra service and we want this single elastic search cluster that needs to be deployed at multiple stacks using different namespace

Comment: Please refine/reword your question: what do you mean by „deployed at multiple stacks“? Just the (server) software, or also the data? And what does „namespace“ mean in your context?

Comment: sorry for the confusion let say I created an elastic search cluster and I have given namespace as user1 and i also created another namespace user2 where another user will access the same cluster but he will not see the user1 details it 's basically like achieving multi-tenancy

Comment: @SauravNarayan in case my answer helped you, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. Your wording is confusing. What you are looking for is `multi-tenant` cluster. Your last comment clarifies it.

Yes, that can be easily achieved using RBAC. The key thing here is to create `separate .kibana` indices so that one user cannot access Visualisations, Dashboards of another user.

1. Using `elastic superuser`, create the below 2 roles:
   a) `user1_role` that has `all` privileges for indices prefixed `user1*`
   b) `user2_role` that has `all` privileges for indices prefixed `user2*`
   c) Also include `monitor` and `manage_index_templates` roles for the above
2. Next, create `user1` and assign `user1_role` to it apart from assigning `monitoring_user`, `kibana_system` etc roles
3. Repeat step 2 for `user2`.
4. Install kibana in one node, say node1 and configure `kibana.yml` such that it has `kibana.index: user1-kibana`.
5. Install another kibana in another node, say node2 and configure `kibana.yml` such that it has `kibana.index: user2-kibana`.

This means that `user1's` dashboards, visualisations etc will be stored in `user1-kibana` which only `user1` has access to. Same for `user2`.

There you go. A single ES cluster serving multiple-tenants each operating independently.